# Software for electrodynamics and electrostatics simulation?

Tags: simulation, cad

In the past I have been working with Matlab to do simulations of electro-statics and electro-dynamics. More specifically solving the Maxwell equations for given structures and setups. I am now looking for specifically designed software to use.

#### Requirements:

1. **Speed**. (Faster is better)
2. Whether the software can use **GPU calculations** (Cuda exc..). (Comsol does not).
3. **Ease of use** (Does it support coding? How easy it is to create structures? Can structures and materials be imported?)
4. **licensed for Multiple machines** and workstations (this is for university work).

So far I have considered: Comsol and Matlab.

Comment: Thank you Oxinabox. That was the original intent.